# Polynomial Transformation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, graphing-functions

I'm currently at Desmos & GeoGebra tinkering with my project. I wanted to form a two letter A's with a domain restriction cutting its legs beneath it. **How do I enlarge this polynomial equation in every possible direction?** **(like double or triple its original size)?**

$$y=-4.6x^4-2.6x^3+9.9x^2+2.9x+4.2$$

It seems that changing the variables present within, only increases its height and that's not what I wanted to happen. **Moreover, what variable should I add/remove within the expression** to come up with that endeavor of mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any function $y(x)$, use $2y(x/2)$ to double it. In general $\lambda y(x/\lambda)$ scales it by $\lambda$ in both $x$ and $y$ directions.

For your specific example, $$Y(x)=2(-4.6 (x/2)^4 - 2.6 (x/2)^3 + 9.9 (x/2)^2 + 2.9 (x/2) + 4.2)$$ does the trick.